# Push a scala project to Heroku using Git - Error for sbt.version

Tags: git, scala, heroku

I always get the same error:

```
-----> Scala app detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 1.6...done
 !      Error, your scala project must include project/build.properties and defi
ne sbt.version
 !      You must use a release verison of sbt, sbt.version=0.11.0 or greater

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Scala app

To git@heroku.com:polar-ravine-8040.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:polar-ravine-8040.git'
```

I have got the `build.properties` in place as suggested but this does not work. I have sbt version 0.13.1 installed on my machine . Also would like to change OpenJdk 1.6 to use java 7 , placed a `system.properites` file in the project but does not work either.

Comment: Is your `build.properties` file in a `project` subdirectory in the root of your project? Heroku is [very picky about where](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-scala#declare-dependencies-with-sbt) [certain files are located](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-scala#optionally-choose-a-jdk). The `system.properties` file should be directly in the root.

Answer (score 1):

Remove any extraneous whitespace (e.g., a blank line at the end of the build.properties file). See https://github.com/ghostm/lift_blank_heroku/issues/1.

**Update**

The issue may be that sbt 13.1 is not yet supported by the Heroku Scala buildpack. See https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala/issues/56.